# GWT and JxBrowser - any experiences?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, obfuscation, jxbrowser

I am developing a client-server-based web application using a canvas component to display data I received from the server.

Now I got the following problem: The Data generated by the Server is just too much to be transferred uncompressed to the clients, I am expecting Data amounts of > 1 MB per second in the final application, altough I only transfer the minimal amount of data required by the client.

Via Data compression I could solve that problem, but if I compress the data, my client won't be able to decompress it fast enough within JavaScript. The result is that my screen is laggy.

The solution would be to run the decompressing in a seperate thread so the screen won't be affected.

Just now I came across JxBrowser: http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/

It's a Library that would allow to run my web application inside a JFrame on a client machine, while another thread is handling the client-server communication and the decompression of the data.

The last step would be to transfer the decompressed Data to the Web browser in my JFrame.

But now I don't know how I could directly access an obfuscated JavaScript function of my GWT client to transfer my decompressed data.

Has anybody done similar things already, or tried that and came to the result that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing around with JavaFX to host GWT applications on the desktop. JavaFX contains a webkit (that is not outdated) which seems to be a very good host for gwt apps.

You might want to take a look into JavaFX.

Comment: Hey there!

thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look on JavaFX. :-)

Comment: Okay, I sucessfully managed to get my Web Application into a JavaFx-Scene, but this was the easy part. How can I make the GWT application interact with my Scene or the other way around? Are there special interfaces?